# Build in variety Collection

Tags: build-automation

**how can configure synchronous Build in variety Collection?**
I need Multi-BuildController for variety Collection. Is the solution to manually install another build service and register another build controller to the 2nd collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason we have separate Team Project Collections is that we have different departments and people are involved in different  projects form different  departments(i.e. web, desktop, data processing, mobile programming). So want to let every body see the related collection to himself and not  those of others.